# Python uncode output

Tags: python

I want to see the normal output of the string

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://new.cpc.com.tw/division/mb/oil-more1-1.aspx'
html = requests.get(url).text
sp = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
data = sp.find_all('span',{'id':'Showtd'})
rows = data[0].find_all('tr')

prices = list()
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
if len(cols[1].text) > 0:
    item = [s[0].text,cols[1].text,cols[2].text,cols[3].text,]
    prices.append(item)    
for p in prices:
    print p
```

Its output:

> [u'113F 1209800', u'98\u7121\u925b\u6c7d\u6cb9', u'\u6563\u88dd', u'\u4e00\u822c\u81ea\u7528\u5ba2\u6236 ']

My expected output:

> [2016/01/18', 18.4', 19.9, 21.9']

How should I fix it?

Comment: Don't print a list? Just print the individual elements of each list, or join the list into a string. You are looking at *debugging output* (like all containers, lists don't have a 'friendly' output).

Comment: Your list contains `113F 1209800 98無鉛汽油 散裝 一般自用客戶` (from `print ' '.join(p)`.

Comment: wow!That's work! thx!!!

Comment: so if i use the list to output you say it doesn't have a 'friendly' output ,that's mean it doesn't support the unicode?

Comment: It does support Unicode, see the duplicate. The *representation* of the values is ASCII-friendly to avoid issues with printing on terminals that don't support Unicode, but all those `\uhhhh` escape sequences are Unicode values. Note that ASCII text is *also* Unicode.